# Proof that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

After proving this [image]

The author says this[image]

But if I let $q = 2^2.3.5....p + 1$ instead, and use theorem $11$, then doesn't that prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4n + 1$?

Comment: No, because $q$ may be a product of primes all of which are of the form $4n+3$.

Comment: For example, $3 \times 7 = 21 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not. $q$ could still be a product of all primes that are of the form $4n + 3$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice $(4a+3)(4b+3)$ is of form $4t+1$.

So a number of form $4t+1$ can be made by multiplying only the primes of form $4a+3$